# Python Mock call order with incomplete call list

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

My goal is to find out whether a function from one object was called before another function of another object.

```
class A:
    def foo( self ):
       ...

    def foo2( self ):
       ...

class B:
    def goo( self ):
       ...

class C:
    def func( self, a: A, b: B ):
       a.foo()
       a.foo2()
       b.goo()
```

With my unit test, I would like to find out whether `a.foo()` was called before `b.goo()`.
I already tried it like in the following code, but obviously, it did not work because there was the call off `a.foo2()` in between.

```
class SomeTests( unittest.TestCase ):
    def test_callOrder( self ):
        aMock = Mock()
        bMock = Mock()
        topMock = Mock()
        topMock.attach_mock( aMock, 'a' )
        topMock.attach_mock( bMock, 'b' )

        c = C()
        c.func( aMock, bMock )    

        expectedCalls = []
        expectedCalls.append( call.a.foo() )
        expectedCalls.append( call.b.goo() )
        topMock.assert_has_calls( expectedCalls, any_order=False )
```

How can I ignore the call of `a.foo2()` and just focus assertion on `a.foo()` and `b.goo()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no specific check for this, you have to do 2 tests: first check that both functions are called, then check that they are called in the correct order:

```py
class SomeTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_callOrder(self):
        ...

        c = C()
        c.func(aMock, bMock)

        expectedCalls = [call.a.foo(), call.b.goo()]
        topMock.assert_has_calls(expectedCalls, any_order=True)
        self.assertGreater(topMock.mock_calls.index(call.b.goo()),
                           topMock.mock_calls.index(call.a.foo()))
```

The first call (`assert_has_calls` with `any_order=True`) will succeed if the functions are called at all, regardless of order and other calls in-between. The second check relies on the `mock_calls` property which allows for more checks, if there are no appropriate convenience functions.